# get set help using a structure and arraylist

Tags: c#, struct, get, set

[enter link description here](http://gyazo.com/87d4cf250106d67dad0c3f7d1cb5b2e1)I am trying to make (private int vr;) to work in the loop so I could change it easily, however I have no idea how to make a get / set for this, or If i have to use get set at all.
I hope this is enough information if further info in necessary please leave a comment saying so.

```
    struct mp3players
    {

        private int ID;
        private string Make;
        private string Model;
        private int MBSize;
        private double Price;
        private int vr;

        public int id
        {
            get { return this.ID; }
            set { this.ID = value; }
        }

        public string make
        {
            get { return this.Make; }
            set { this.Make = value; }
        }

        public string model
        {
            get { return this.Model; }
            set { this.Model = value; }
        }

        public int mbsize
        {
            get { return this.MBSize; }
            set { this.MBSize = value; }
        }

        public double price
        {
            get { return this.Price; }
            set { this.Price = value; }
        }

        public int VR
        {
            get { return this.vr; }
            set { this.vr = value; }
        }
    } 

    private static ArrayList mps;
    static void mp3()
    {
        mp3players mp1 = new mp3players();
        mp1.id = 1;
        mp1.make = "GET technologies .inc";
        mp1.model = "HF 410 ";
        mp1.mbsize = 4096;
        mp1.price = 129.95;
        mp1.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp2 = new mp3players();
        mp2.id = 2;
        mp2.make = "Far & Loud";
        mp2.model = "XM 600 ";
        mp2.mbsize = 8192;
        mp2.price = 224.95;
        mp2.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp3 = new mp3players();
        mp3.id = 3;
        mp3.make = "Innotivative";
        mp3.model = "Z3 ";
        mp3.mbsize = 512;
        mp3.price = 79.95;
        mp3.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp4 = new mp3players();
        mp4.id = 4;
        mp4.make = "Resistance S.A.";
        mp4.model = "3001 ";
        mp4.mbsize = 4096;
        mp4.price = 124.95;
        mp4.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp5 = new mp3players();
        mp5.id = 5;
        mp5.make = "CBA";
        mp5.model = "NXT volume ";
        mp5.mbsize = 2048;
        mp5.price = 159.05;
        mp5.VR = 500;

        mps = new ArrayList();
        mps.Add(mp1);
        mps.Add(mp2);
        mps.Add(mp3);
        mps.Add(mp4);
        mps.Add(mp5);         
    }

    static void mutteer()
    {
        int i = 1;
        int a;

        startloop:
        while (i == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wat is het Id van de mp3 speler?");
            try
            {
                a = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dat is geen nummer waarde!");
                goto startloop;
            }

            if (a == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wat is het nieuwe voorraad");
                try
                {
```

as you can see I wrote vr here what obviously doesn't work,
 I need to use the set and get here in my understanding but how do I get a get and set to work with it?

```
                    VR = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    i = 2;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Dat is geen nummer waarde!");
                    goto startloop;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Basically, avoid mutable structs. They're painful. Why are you using structs at all? I'd also strongly recommend that you look into automatically implemented properties, and naming conventions. (Normally your private fields would start with lower case characters, but your public properties would start with upper case characters.)

Comment: I have to use a struct its unavoidable else I would have never done so, that is the problem.

Comment: But *why* do you have to use a struct? Any time you want to do something highly unusual and non-idiomatic, you should explain your reasons - so that with any luck, it can be avoided. It would also really help if you could make your question include a *short* but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - your current code is neither of those.

Comment: the assignment states I have to use a struct (its a school project) Basicly the VR = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); needs to be changed to a amount you want to add and than the amount you put in has to be seen on a different tab. (Ill add a picture in the question.) what is happening on the picture is you choose the id and than the amount, when the disired  ammount (voorraad) is chosen the amount (voorraad) should change of the id

Comment: @JonSkeet, the problem isn't that he's using structs, it's that there is no instance of a struct in place and therefore VR = is meaningless!

Comment: yes the vr is meaningless that is what I try`d to say in the explanation, but how do I fix it though that is the problem. sorry i`m bad at explanations

Comment: Again, your question would be considerably clearer if you could condense the question into a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem. I would also suggest talking to whoever set the task, suggesting that a struct isn't appropriate as a mutable data type. (There may be an alternative solution using an *immutable* struct, of course...)